# Google Website Translator Prevent Specific Sections from translating

Tags: google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am trying to use Google's Website Translator Customization. **(Where you just grab the meta tag and snippet of code they have you insert into your website page).** And I am trying to figure out if there is a way to have the Google Translate skip certain sections of the page.

For example:

I have a dropdown of states and for some reason when it tries to translate the states it changes the states to some random abbreviation. Like Delaware may turn into something like Del in Spanish.

If anyone has any information on how to block certain parts or skip certain parts that Google tries to translate please let me know I have been searching everywhere and cannot find any documentation on this.

I am hoping that there is a special way to just code "don't translate this"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `class="notranslate"` to the elements that shouldn´t be translated. To prevent the whole page from being translated, add `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">`

Answer (score 0):

Adding class="notranslate" prevents Google translate from translating specific section(s).

```
Illustration: 

 Hello Google :), That's a <span class="notranslate">good</span> website!.
```

If it is going to be translated to french for example, it will be: Bonjour Google :), ce est un *good* site web!.

If using different languages though, variety of confusion may arise. So the simpler the structure of the sentence is, the more it will get translated in such a good proper way.